# A boy eats a freshly pounded rice cake

Tags: tense

In an AP photo, I found the following sentence.
A boy eats a freshly pounded rice cake.
I'd like to know the usage of simple present tense in this sentence. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what it is that you want to know regarding the tenses. But I'll try explaining it form what I've understood from your question:

> **The boy eats a freshly pounded rice cake**

At the time when the photo was taken, the boy was eating the freshly pounded rice cake. Now, at this time, when I talk about it, I use the past tense as both the events, which are:

1. The boy eating the cake.
2. The capturing of the image of the boy while he was eating the cake.

So, the present tense is used. The tagline you found with the image is in present because it describes the image as it is happening now.

Comment: The use of the present tense in this way to describe an event in the past is supposed to make the description more immediate and real for the reader. There are many, many jokes that start off "A man walks into a bar..." : this also is using the present tense to describe an event that (in the context of the joke) occurred in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This use is called the [Historical Present](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/histpreterm.htm) (or the Literary Present). As JavaLatte noted, the Historical Present is often used to give a sense of immediacy to past events, or to describe literature or art -- such as this photo.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

I'm guessing that what you are asking about is not the use of a present (as the other answerers seem to have assumed) but the use of the simple present as opposed to the present continuous.

I believe the answer is that this is effectively a title, rather than a narrative.

If you asked a native English speaker to describe the picture, they would say "A boy is eating ... " rather than "A boy eats ... ".

In describing the picture as an object, they would say "A picture which shows a boy eating ... " or "A picture in which a boy is eating ... "

But when we give a title to the picture, we're far more likely to use the simple present: "Johnny eats a rice cake", or "Johnny has a snack" or whatever it is.

By convention, the caption on a photo, even if it is not formally a title, follows the grammar of titles and does not usually use a continuous verb form.